# Когда вызывается конструктор преобразования? (С++)

Tags: c++, конструктор, преобразование

Конструктор преобразования вызывается в 3 случаях. В каких именно?

Comment: Почему в трёх случаях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим есть следующий класс:

```
class MyIntClass
{
private:
    int val_;
public:
    MyIntClass(int val) : val_(val) {}   // Тот самый конструктор преобразования
};
```

Вот случаи, когда будет вызван именно этот конструктор:

1. При использовании синтаксиса присваивания для инициализации обьекта значением типа `int`. Т.е. типа аргумента конструктора преобразования.

```
MyIntClass obj = 1; // Вызов конструктора преобразования.
```

2. При передаче в функцию значения типа `int`, которая ожидает обьект класса `MyIntClass`.

```
void func(MyIntClass mic) {}
...
func(1); // Вызов конструктора преобразования для создания обьекта класса MyIntClass.
```

3. Когда функция обьявлена как возвращающая `MyIntClass`, но в теле возвращает `int`.

```
MyIntClass func()
{
    return 1; // Вызов конструктора преобразования для создания обьекта класса MyIntClass.
}
```

4. Как заметил [dIm0n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398802/dim0n), конструктор преобразования также вызывается при преобразовании `int` в `MyIntClass` используя операторы преобразования.

```
static_cast<MyIntClass>(1); // Вызов конструктора преобразования для создания обьекта класса MyIntClass.
```

5. Когда уже созданному обьекту `MyIntClass` присваивается значение `int`, а в классе `MyIntClass` нет соответствующей операции присваивания и используется обычная `operator=(const MyIntClass&)`.

```
MyIntClass obj{1};
obj = 2;
```

Это также относится и к другим типам, которые могут быть преобразованы в `int`. Например, если в всех выше описаных случаях будут использоваться значения типа `short` вместо `int`. В таком случае эти значения преобразуются в `int`, а затем уже в `MyIntClass`.

Comment: Первые 3 пункта не будут работать для `explicit` конструктора преобразования

Comment: @dIm0n Ну так это понятно. Поэтому он и не обьявлен как `explicit` в классе)

Comment: В условии не сказано, что он не `explicit`

Comment: @dIm0n В условии также не сказано, что он `explicit`;)

Comment: @dIm0n [Converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) по определению не `explicit`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat согласен, имелось в виду именно это в вопросе, наверное