# Неявное приведение в конструкторе класса

Tags: c++

есть класс :

```
class myclass{
 int a;
 public:
 myclass(int p){a=p;};
};

int main()
{
 myclass mc=33; 
 myclass mc2=myclass(33);
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в 1 варианте?
Во втором , я понимаю, что создается класс myclass , вызывается конструктор для него , и этот класс экземпляр копируется в mc2.

Comment: увы, но ваше понимание не верно, так как во втором случае конструктор копирования вызван не будет

Comment: что же касается 1-ого варианта - это из-за того, что вы конструктор преобразования не пометили как `explicit`

Comment: Происходит вызов указанного конструктора, только же был вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1175128/398802. Кстати, лучше использовать member initializer list, а не присваивать значение в теле конструктора. А вот про второй вариант https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, ваши предположения о том, что происходит во втором варианте ошибочны. Коснтруктор копирования не будет вызван, вы можете это проверить сами если, например, удалите конструктор копирования (может не сработать, это зависит от компилятора) или добавите в него логи. Дело в том, что компилятор упрощает такие вызовы до простого вызова конструктора. Считайте что это оптимизация, которую нельзя отключить (насколько мне известно).

Во-вторых, первый вариант записи возможен из-за того, что ваш конструктор не помечен как `explicit`. В общем случае это все конструкторы с одним параметром следует помечать как `explicit`, чтобы избежать неявного преобразования (как в вашем примере).

Проверочный код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class myclass {
  int a;

public:
  explicit myclass(int p) { a = p; };
  myclass(const myclass &) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; };
};

int main() {
  // XXX fail
  // myclass mc = 33;
  myclass mc2 = myclass(33);
}
```

Comment: *"упрощает такие вызовы до простого вызова конструктора. Считайте что это оптимизация, которую нельзя отключить"* Это гарантированно происходит в C++17. До этого компилятор тоже имел право не создавать лишние объекты, но перемещающий конструктор должен был существовать в любом случае.

Comment: Не согласен, что  "В общем случае это все конструкторы с одним параметром следует помечать как explicit". Есть много примеров, где неявное преобразование является преимуществом типа.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan абсолютно согласен, поэтому-то и формулировка такая: "в общем случае", "следует". Тобишь: обычно нужно, но если вы уверены в том что делаете - пожалуйста